# Creating quick coarse scale preview (JPEG/PNG) of raster mosaic using GDAL?

Tags: raster, gdal, imagery

The script I developed stacks and mosaic satellite imagery, and the resultant imagery is in some cases "50GBs" in size. Therefore opening the image in a GIS environment to check the mosaic is sluggish and slow.

Is there anyway I can quickly create a JPEG/PNG overview/preview (it can be very coarse) of the big mosaic so that the users can quickly check the imagery using the preview file instead of opening/loading the 50GB image mosaic?

Comment: Create virtual mosaic with gdalbuildvrt http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html and then do "gdal_translate -of png -outsize 1000 1000 input.vrt quicklook.png".

Comment: I will give that a try...thanks @user30184

Comment: @user30184... the output is black?

Comment: What is the bit depth of your imagery? 8-bit, 32-bit?

Answer (score 1):

What worked (from comment by @user30184) can be found in the following article:
https://spectraldifferences.wordpress.com/2013/08/17/quick-look-image-of-a-multi-image-mosaic/

That guide worked for me.